# Proper Use of Move Semantics in This Situation?

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry if the title is a bit vague; I will try to clarify it thru some examples. Suppose I have a class Foo, which contains an init method:

```
class Foo{
    auto init(const BigMemoryHungryType& t) -> void {
        //do a ton of stuff
    }
};
```

Now suppose that I would like to create an overload of this init method, this time accepting an rvalue of type BigMemoryHungryType, so that I can simply perform move semantics:

```
class Foo{
    auto init(const BigMemoryHungryType& t) -> void {
        //do a ton of stuff
    }

    auto init(BigMemoryHungryType&& t) -> void {
        //exact same as other init, but utilizing move semantics
    }

};
```

How could I keep the copy-paste to a minimum here? The method I'm thinking of involves assigning all the members in both init methods, then calling a protected/private init method to do the actual work:

```
class Foo{
    auto init(const BigMemoryHungryType& t) -> void {
        real_t = t;
        init();
    }

    auto init(BigMemoryHungryType&& t) -> void {
        real_t = std::move(t);
        init();
    }

private:
    auto init() -> void {
        //do actual work
    }

    BigMemoryHungryType real_t;
};
```

This seems fine and all, however it violates the strong exception guarantee if init() throws an exception. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: What do you mean, "if Foo throws an exception"?

Comment: `auto init(BigMemoryHungryType t) -> void {init(std::move(t));}`

Comment: fix'd. @Bryan: that creates a temporary

Comment: it does more move (which is cheap), but still one copy

Comment: @bryan: how could i be so dense? post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
auto init(BigMemoryHungryType t) -> void {
   init(std::move(t));
}
```

it will copy `BigMemoryHungryType` once to temporary and move it to the instance field in the move overload

Comment: one last thing: if i have multiple memory hungry types in the init method, do i have to write a new init function for each additional type?

Comment: not exactly sure what do you mean. but you may try template solution `template <class T1, class T2> void init(T1 && t1, T2 && t2) { _t1 = std::move(t1); _t2 = std::move(t2); }` try google "universal reference"